# How do I use an aggregate function, such as `max` with Panache?

Tags: quarkus-panache

How do I use an aggregate function, such as `max` with Panache for Quarkus?

I can make it work if I interact directly with the entity manager like this:

```
    Query query = MyPanacheEntity.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT max(someProperty) FROM MyPanacheEntity m WHERE m.anotherProperty=:anotherProperty");
    query.setParameter("anotherProperty", "xyz");
    Integer maxSomeProperty = (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
```

But is it possible to do the same without interacting directly with the entity manager? I.e. something in line with:

```
   Integer maxSomeProperty = MyPanacheEntity.select("max(someProperty) where anotherProperty = ?!", "xyz").singleResult();
```